# Spark is running python 3.7.6 but spark context is showing python 2.7. How to fix using the spark context?

Tags: python, apache-spark, version, amazon-emr, amazon-sagemaker

I have installed sagemaker using `sc.install_pypi_package("sagemaker==2.5.1")`. However, I get the following error when I try to import sagemaker and it is pointing to python2.7.

[image: cannot import name git_utils]

I checked my EMR master node running pyspark and the version there is pyspark 2.4.5 running python 3.7.6.

[image]

So then I tried to upgrade the python version of my spark context but it says

> "ValueError: Package already installed for current Spark context!"

[image]

So I thought lemme try uninstalling python2.7 from spark context and that does not let me do it, saying

> "Not uninstalling python at /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload, outside
> environment /tmp/1598628537004-0"

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I believe the sagemaker import is failing due to spark context referring python2.7. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referred to this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/install-python-libraries-on-a-running-cluster-with-emr-notebooks/) and updated the python version of spark context to python3. This fixes the issue:

```
%%configure -f
{ "conf":{
          "spark.pyspark.python": "python3",
          "spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled": "true",
          "spark.pyspark.virtualenv.type":"native",
          "spark.pyspark.virtualenv.bin.path":"/usr/bin/virtualenv"
         }
}
```